# Cast [AnyObject] to generic type that may or may not be a collection type

Tags: swift, generics, casting

I have an array of `AnyObject`, and I would like to cast it (or *one* of its objects) to a generic type `T` which may or may not be an array.

My first attempt:

```
class MyClass<T> {

    func someMethod() -> T? {

        let anyObjectArray: [AnyObject] = // ... array obtained from Objective-C framework

        if let objectsAsCollection = anyObjectArray as? T {  // Cast always fails
            return objectsAsCollection
        } else if let firstObject = anyObjectArray.first as? T {
            return firstObject
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

The first `if let` cast fails when `T` is an `Array` (e.g. `T.self == Array<SomeObject>.self`).

I would try something like this, but it involves introducing another generic parameter somehow, so isn’t valid as written:

```
extension MyClass where T == Array<U> {

    fun someMethod() -> T? {

        let anyObjectArray: [AnyObject] = // ... array obtained from Objective-C framework

        if let objectsAsCollection = anyObjectArray.flatMap({ $0 as? U }) {
            return objectsAsCollection
        } else if let firstObject = anyObjectArray.first as? T {
            return firstObject
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

---

The reason for wanting to do this is that I am using an Objective-C framework (RestKit) to get results from a REST API. I am building a layer on top in Swift which passes these results back as a specific type depending on the request that was made, so I have a `Result` type that looks something like this:

```
enum Result<T>: {
    case Success(T)
    case Failure(Error)
}
```

Sometimes `T` is a single object, sometimes it is an arrays of objects, but the Objective-C framework always returns results as an array.

Comment: This will be difficult without a constraint of how many _different_ types of objects the `AnyObject` array holds. E.g., say your `[AnyObject]` holds `NSString` as well as an `NSNumber` instances: how are these to be casted to an array of a native Swift type? Remember that, generally, using a generic, say `T`, allows for different-types to call the method, but for each such call, `T` is fixed to one single type. Do you know for certain that the `AnyObject` array will always only contain single same type objects?

Comment: @dfri The `AnyObject` array returned from the Objective-C framework can in theory contain any type. However, in reality I know that the REST API returns an array of a specific type, so for each call `T` is either `SomeType` or `Array<SomeType>` (where `SomeType` varies depending on what type of object is being returned by the server).

Comment: I think I was discussing exactly the same problem recently with someone else and we solved that by replacing `[AnyObject]` with `NSArray`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following syntax will work:

```
class MyClass<T> {
    func someMethod() -> T? {
        // let's not convert to [AnyObject] here, keep it as NSArray
        let anyObjectArray: NSArray = ...

        // For some reason conversion from [AnyObject] to [T] fails...
        // However, conversion from NSArray is special
        if let objectsAsCollection = anyObjectArray as? T {
            return objectsAsCollection
        } else if let firstObject = (anyObjectArray as [AnyObject]).first as? T {
            return firstObject
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

However, it is just a workaround for a probable bug. We can boil down the problem to the following:

```
class GenericClass<T> {
    func someMethod() {
        let anyObjectArray: [AnyObject] = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]

        print(T) //Array<String>
        print(T.self == Array<String>.self) //true

        print(anyObjectArray is [String]) //true
        print(anyObjectArray is T) //false - BUG
    }
}

let instance = GenericClass<[String]>()
instance.someMethod()
```

(reported: [SR-1054](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1054))

which looks like a clear bug to me. It actually looks like another instance of the bug discussed in [Type of optionals cannot be inferred correctly in swift 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36160934/type-of-optionals-cannot-be-inferred-correctly-in-swift-2-2/36177547#36177547)

Comment: Oh how brilliantly simple, thanks! It’s not the first quirk of typecasting between Objective-C and Swift I’ve encountered, but I didn’t expect the solution to be quite so easy. Do you know why the cast from `NSArray` is treated differently? I’m guessing something to do with Objective-C’s dynamic runtime, but I’m not sure how that interacts with Swift generics...

Comment: @Stuart Hmmm, I thought I knew the reason but I was wrong. This looks more like a workaround. I will try to inspect it a bit more. Just today we were reporting a bug with casting to a generic type so maybe this is also a bug.

Comment: @Stuart I think I have a proof that it is a bug.

Comment: That proof looks pretty conclusive to me, especially since it doesn’t touch the Obj-C runtime. Thanks for going to the trouble of adding it to your answer. I’ll file a bug report citing your example.