# Type of optionals cannot be inferred correctly in swift 2.2

Tags: swift, swift2

**Problem:**

When running the following code under Xcode 7.3 with swift 2.2, the compiler is unable to correctly infer the type of the optional:

```
import Foundation

func whatAmI<T>(inout property:T?)
{
    switch property {
    case is Int?:
        print("I am an Int?")
    case is String?:
        print("I am a String?")
    default:
        print("I don't know what I am")
    }
}

var string : String?
whatAmI(&string)
```

On my side with Xcode 7.3 this will print `I am an Int?`

However, when I initialize the variable with an empty string before passing it to the function, the switch infers it to be a String?.

This would print `I am a String?` in the previous Xcode version.

Are you getting similar results?

**Observations:**

The same occurs when using this function signature:

```
func whatAmI(property:AnyObject?)
```

**-- Bug --**

This issue is a regression in swift 2.2:
https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1024

Comment: This seems like a very strange behavior, it might actually be a bug. I can see that `T` has been inferred as `String` and `(nil as T?) is Int?` will pass but `(nil as String?) is Int?` will fail.

Comment: Strange: this works for me on Swift 2.1.1 i.e. the program outputs `I am a String?`

Comment: I'd suggest filing a bug report. Very nice indeed.

Comment: Whoa. If you reverse the order of the `case` statements, it says `I am a String?`. So it's just going for the first one, whatever it is.

Comment: Filed a bug report: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1024

Comment: @Braiam why did you remove the swift2.2 and Xcode7.3 tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. The minimal example is the following:

```
func genericMethod<T>(property: T?) {
    print(T) // String

    let stringNil = Optional<String>.None

    print(stringNil is String?) // true (warning - always true)    
    print(stringNil is T?) // true

    let intNil = Optional<Int>.None

    print(intNil is String?) // false (warning - always fails)
    print(intNil is T?) // true - BUG
}

genericMethod("")
```