# Swift 2.2 breaks optionals/unwrapping optionals

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Swift 2.2 has broken almost all my code. Even this simple string assigning to label doesn't work anymore:

```
cell.categoryName.text = peopleArray![indexPath.row]["Name"] as? String
```

The error says "**Downcast from 'String?!' to 'String'  only unwraps optionals, did you mean to use '!!'?**"

What changes do I have to do now.

**EDIT**:

More Problems:

```
if (dict["data"]!["DataDetails"] as! NSArray).count == 0 {
}
```

Due to this I am getting a segmentation fault and the error shows this: **warning: cast from 'String?!' to unrelated type 'NSArray' always fails**

**UPDATE:**

I was using NSDictionaries, NSArrays in my classes that seems to cause the problem. Changing all the literals from Obj-C to swift made the code work properly. 
So, I will also recommend other developers to prefer swift literals.

Comment: use `peopleArray!["Name"] as! String`  .. but I suggest Don't use force unwrap  .. use if let

Comment: Swift 2.2 has a regression with regards to type inference of optionals -- your problem might stem from that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36160934/type-of-optionals-cannot-be-inferred-correctly-in-swift-2-2

Comment: Can you please write how you have define your `peopleArray`

Answer (score 0):

it seems there are some slight differences when using the swift types and the objective-c NS... types

eg

```
let dic:NSDictionary? = ["a":"a"]

let str:NSString? = dic!["a"] as? NSString

let dic2:Dictionary? = ["b":"b"]

let str2:String? = dic2!["b"] //dont need to do any casting, already optional

print(str)
print(str2)
```

prints

```
Optional(a)
Optional("b")
```

so depending on how your array / dictionary is defined, you might need different casting/unwrapping

Comment: No it doesn't work. But If i use peopleArray!["Name"]!! as String then it works but I want this to be optional.

Comment: what is `peopleArray` defined as?

Comment: It is defined as NSMutableArray

Comment: you mean an NSMutableDictionary? since you are 'indexing' with a string

Comment: I updated my question. It was just for reference that optionals are not working.

Comment: depending on what type `peopleArray![indexPath.row]` returns you may have to cast this first to a NSDictionary, and then access what you want form the dictionary, unfortunately NSArrays always return `AnyObject`, while swift ones return the assigned type, can you show exactly how you assign the dictionaries and arrays, its quite important to answering your question. alternatively, dont use NSArrays and NSDictionaries in swift if you can

Comment: Can you please check the updated question above. I'm getting some more problems. Thanks.