# Swift 2.2 compiler forcing Dictionary value to be unwrapped twice

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, option-type

Pre Swift 2.2, the following code example successfully compiled. With 2.2 it gives the compiler error:

```
// launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?
if let options = launchOptions {
    if let notifDict = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] {
        if let phone = notifDict["sender_phone"] {
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "phoneNumber == %@", phone)
            // value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use...
        }
    }
}
```

Why am I getting this error when I've already unwrapped to Dictionary value via `if let`?

NOTE using Xcode 7.3

Comment: What is `notifDict`?

Comment: @dan - updated question

Answer (score 1):

Unwrap the value from the dictionary as as `String`:

```
if let phone = notifDict["sender_phone"] as? String {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "phoneNumber == %@", phone)
    // ...
}
```

This is assuming `notifDict` is of type `[String : AnyObject]`.

Updated answer based on the updated information:

```
let launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]? = [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey: ["sender_phone" : "test"]]
if let options = launchOptions {
    if let notifDict = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] {
        if let phone = notifDict["sender_phone"] as? String {
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "phoneNumber == %@", phone)
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Compiler error "Downcast from 'String?!' to 'String' only unwraps optionals. Did you mean to use '!!'?"

Comment: @hgwhittle What is `notifDict` declared as?

Comment: Issue exists on Xcode 7.3. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36171958/swift-2-2-breaks-optionals-unwrapping-optionals?lq=1

Comment: @hgwhittle sorry typo, testing on Xcode 7.3/iOS 9.3.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't showed us you how you've defined `notifDict`, but note that the first `if let` clause simply checks *if a value exists for key `"sender_phone"`*. If such a value exists and *if the value itself it is an optional*, it *will not be unwrapped*, simply bound in its optional form to `predicate`.

```
var notifDict : [String: String?] = [:]
notifDict["sender_phone"] = "xxx-xxxxxx"

if let predicate = notifDict["sender_phone"] {
    // predicate is String? here, and needs unwrapping below
    let a = NSPredicate(format: "phoneNumber == %@", predicate ?? "default")
}
```

This answer is assuming `notifDict` is of type `[String: String?]`. If not (say, of type `[String: AnyObject]`, see [@JAL:s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36271501/4573247)).

Answer (score 0):

I am having same problem since Xcode 7.3. In my case, when I inspect the type of the `userInfo` (`notifDict` for you) in the **Variables View**, I notice that it is:

[image]

which is `AnyObject!` instead of the expected type `[String: String?]`.

What I did is unwrap the dicitonary first before using it:

```
guard let myUserInfo = userInfo as? [String:String] else {
    return
}
```

It might be related to this bug where swift 2.2 is not able to infer the type property https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1024 and I guess they might change the behaviour again later.